# Problematic white spaces while reading a file

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am parsing a html document with this code:

```
ifstream myfile("file.html");

  string line;
  int m_lines;
  char c;

  while(getline(myfile,line)) {
    if(line.empty()) {
      m_lines++;
      continue;
    }
    istringstream iss(line);

    while(iss.good()) {
      c = iss.get();
      //my code here (not important for this question)
      cout << c;
    }


    m_lines++;
  }
```

input file (file.html) look like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <strong>haha</strong> gfadf.</p>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="alt" />
```

output:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum golo gama<strong>haha</strong> gfadf.</p> <img src="image.jpg" alt="alt" />
                                                        ^
                                                        ^
                                                        ^
```

If there is a new line in input file, it prints a white space character. How can I skip or delete this character?

Comment: you don't want to use an `if()`??
 Like, 
`if (c!='\n' && c!='\r') { cout<<c };`?

Comment: I have tried... it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your streams do not have newlines in them, when `getline` is called it extracts characters up to to the newline. `iss.get()` is returning the **end-of-file** as there are no more characters to extract. You can check it with the following code:

```
while(iss.good()) {
    c = iss.get();
    if (c == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
    {
        cout << "end of file!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the last character in the string is a white-space character (such as `\f\n\r\t\v`..) and delete it. Example:

```
while (line.back() == '\s')
{
    line.erase(line.end());
}
```

If you're not using c++11 (`.back()` was added in c++11)

```
while (line[line.size()-1] == '\s')
{
    line.erase(line.end());
}
```

You can add that before `istringstream iss(line);` and it removes all the trailing white-space characters.